# CGI vs. Long-Running Server

Tags: http, cgi

Can someone please explain this excerpt from golang's documentation on CGI:

"
Note that using CGI means starting a new process to handle each request, which is typically less efficient than using a long-running server. This package is intended primarily for compatibility with existing systems. 
"

I use CGI to make database puts and gets.

Is this inefficient?  Should I be using a 'long-running server'?

If so what does that mean, and how do I implement it?

... http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/cgi/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is inefficient. The cost of starting a whole new process is generally much more than just connecting through to an already-existing process, or doing something on a thread within the current process.

In terms of whether it's necessary, that depends. If you're creating a search engine to rival Google, I would suggest CGI is *not* the way to go.

If it's a personal website accessed once an hour, I think you can probably get away with it.

In terms of a long running server, you can generally write something like a plug-in for a web server which is running all the time and the web server just passes off requests to it when needed (and possibly multiple threads of "it").

That way, it's ready all the time, you don't have to wait while the web server starts another process to handle the request.

In fact, Apache itself does CGI via a module (like a plug-in) which integrates itself into Apache at runtime - the actual calling of external processes is handled *from* that module. The source code, if you think it will help, can be found in `mod_cgi.c` if you do a web search for it.

Another example is `mod_perl` which is a Perl interpreter module, available at [this link](http://perl.apache.org/).

Comment: Can you link to an example of such a plug-in so I can see how this sort of thing is put together and utilised?  Thanks

Comment: So if I use mod_cgi with my Apache server and I write a python CGI script started by an html POST it will start up within the mod_cgi module, stead its own unique process, as long as I specify the script with a handler?  Solving this issue of inefficiency?

Comment: @PrincePeregrine: no, `mod_cgi` is a module that runs _within_ Apache, yes. But its responsibility is to start _other_ processes via the CGI  (ie, as external processes). If you want your Python code running within Apache, you need mod_python: http://www.modpython.org/

Comment: I have both mod_cgi and mod_python modules on my Apache server, if my script uses import cgi blah blah, import mod_python blah blah does that mean that these scripts will not be run by starting their own processes but rather by searching out handler specified relevant functions within them?  Leaving these scripts to function as something akin to a psuedo library?

Answer (score 0):

One option to look into is fastcgi which is a long running server program that doesn't continually restart each request. It used to be that fast cgi had its disadvantages due to memory leaks over time in languages like C, C++, FPC, etc. since they are not garbage collected.  A small memory leak in one fastcgi program after millions of hits to the website could bring the server down, whereas regular old CGI was a garbage collector itself: the program restarted and therefore cleaned up each time someone requested the page and the cgi exited. In the case of Go lang memory leaks are not a concern, however fast cgi could have some hidden gotchyas such as: if golang has any memory leaks in its garbage collector itself... (unlikely, but gotchyas like this might pop up - also heap fragmentation .... over time..)

Generally fastcgi and "long running" is premature optimization. I've seen people with 5 visitors to their personal home page website a day yelling "hey maybe I should use fastcgi" when in fact they would need 5 million visitors a day - but they like to be hip and cool so they start thinking about fast cgi before their site is even known by 3 people.

You need to ask yourself: does the server you are using have a lot of traffic, and by a lot of traffic I don't mean 100 visitors a day... even 1000 unique visitors a day is not a lot.

It is unclear whether you are wanting to write Go lang cgi programs for apache server, or python ones for a go server, or whether you are writing a go server that has cgi capability for python and perl. Clarify what you are actually doing.

As for rivaling Google as a search engine which someone posted about in another answer: if you look at the history of Google they actually coded their programs in C++/C via some cgi system ... rather than using PHP, perl, or other hip and cool stuff that the kids use. Look up backrub project and its template system eons ago. It was called Ctemplate (C compiled programs called upon html templates.....)

https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&q=google+backrub+template+ctemplate

Fastcgi was maybe something that google figured out before there was a fastcgi, or they had their own proprietary solution similar to fastcgi, I don't know since I didn't work at google - but since they used C++/C programs to power google in the old days (and probably still today for some stuff) they must have been using some cgi technology, even if it was modified cgi technology for speed.